# How to know if a script started by wp_cron is still active?

Tags: wp-cron

I have a plugin that uses wp_cron to run jobs, these jobs are quite large sometimes and they seem to have stopped without any indication (0 errors in apache log as well as in the plugin's own log)

So I am wondering if there is a way to be able to check if any of the scripts launched through wp_cron are still active or perhaps timed out?

I know that it is recommended to disable wp_cron and set up an actual cron job that calls wp-cron.php but I need this plugin to work with both an actual cron and a wp-cron.

Thanks for any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called [WP-Cron Control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cron-control/) to check your scheduled events.

Other way to check it is using [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) via command-line, using this command:

```
wp cron event list
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I havent tried with WP-CLI yet but WP-Cron Control only shows the schedule, not if they are actually running